# Rails/MySQL compatibility

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

This is a very quick question. I have not been able to find info on rails/MySQL version compatibility. Anyone know whether rails 3.0.6 plays well with MySQL 5.6 (or at least knows of a good resource so that I can find this on my own)? I am in a CentOS env.

Comment: Are you having some concrete problems? Also, (is it a new app?) is there a reason to use such old rails? It has all those nasty vulnerabilities discovered recently.

Comment: This app is used internally by my employer to report hardware testing result to the test engineers. We got new hardware for our MySql servers which why I'm allowed to upgrade at all. I have inherited the development/maintenance of it since the guy who initially created it has moved on to another company. I'm not so worried about vulnerabilities because one needs to be an employee to even be on our intranet and one needs to be on our intranet to use the app.  I would like to update everything but there's that whole pesky cost/benefit ratio that my company won't approve right now.

Answer (score 2):

Rails doesn't work with mysql, it's the gem you use which does

You should really look into using either the [`mysql`](http://rubygems.org/gems/mysql) or [`mysql2`](http://rubygems.org/gems/mysql2) gem's compatibilities :)

Comment: Thank you. I knew this was way more simple than I had been making it.

Answer (score 0):

Acording to the [documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.0.5/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/MysqlAdapter) you can use the 5.X version.

> The MySQL adapter will work with both Ruby/MySQL, which is a
>   Ruby-based MySQL adapter that comes bundled with Active Record, and
>   with the faster C-based MySQL/Ruby adapter (available both as a gem
>   and from http://www.tmtm.org/en/mysql/ruby/).
>
> Options:
>
> ```
> :host - Defaults to "localhost".
> :port - Defaults to 3306.
> :socket - Defaults to "/tmp/mysql.sock".
> :username - Defaults to "root"
> :password - Defaults to nothing.
> :database - The name of the database. No default, must be provided.
> :encoding - (Optional) Sets the client encoding by executing "SET NAMES <encoding>" after connection.
> :reconnect - Defaults to false (See MySQL documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/auto-reconnect.html).
> :sslca - Necessary to use MySQL with an SSL connection.
> :sslkey - Necessary to use MySQL with an SSL connection.
> :sslcert - Necessary to use MySQL with an SSL connection.
> :sslcapath - Necessary to use MySQL with an SSL connection.
> :sslcipher - Necessary to use MySQL with an SSL connection.
> ```